# Matrix Multiplication Floats

Tags: python

I have a list of constants represented by alpha1, a1 .... theta4.

I can print correctly and read the individual matrices, however when i try matrix multiplication i receive error;

```
print T1 * T2 * T3 * T4
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

I believe it is something to do with multiplying floats.

```
from numpy import matrix
import math

def getTransformationMatrix( alpha, a, d, theta ):
    transformationMatrix = matrix([[math.cos(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(theta),math.sin(alpha)*math.sin(theta) ,a*math.cos(theta)],  [math.sin(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(alpha)  ,-math.sin(alpha)*math.cos(theta),a*math.sin(theta)],[0,math.sin(alpha),math.cos(alpha),d],[0,0,0,1]])
    return[transformationMatrix];

T1 = getTransformationMatrix( alpha1, a1, d1, theta1)
T2 = getTransformationMatrix( alpha2, a2, d2, theta2)
T3 = getTransformationMatrix( alpha3, a3, d3, theta3)
T4 = getTransformationMatrix( alpha4, a4, d4, theta4)

print T1 * T2 * T3 * T4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getTransformationMatrix` function returns a list while you would like it to return a matrix.

I suspect you added those square brackets by mistake.

```
def getTransformationMatrix( alpha, a, d, theta ):
    transformationMatrix = matrix([[math.cos(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(theta),math.sin(alpha)*math.sin(theta) ,a*math.cos(theta)],  [math.sin(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(alpha)  ,-math.sin(alpha)*math.cos(theta),a*math.sin(theta)],[0,math.sin(alpha),math.cos(alpha),d],[0,0,0,1]])
    return [transformationMatrix];
```

Try this:

```
def getTransformationMatrix( alpha, a, d, theta ):
    transformationMatrix = matrix([[math.cos(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(theta),math.sin(alpha)*math.sin(theta) ,a*math.cos(theta)],  [math.sin(theta),math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(alpha)  ,-math.sin(alpha)*math.cos(theta),a*math.sin(theta)],[0,math.sin(alpha),math.cos(alpha),d],[0,0,0,1]])
    return transformationMatrix
```

Seeing this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

the first thing to do is to print no only `T1`, `T2`, etc. but also `type(T1)`, etc.

You would see it is not what you expect.

Comment: Perfect thank you!! and thankyou for the type() tip!

Comment: Glad I helped. Welcome to SO.